# How to get real time data in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am new in programming and I have a question about my project.

I am currently making an ecommerce project using laravel. What I want to do is create a shoping cart with real-time data.
So when I add a product in the cart, at the same time the number of product will be increased in the cart.
Also even the price in total with be changed in real time.

How can i handle this situation ? Should I use javascript ? Can you please give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

You will use a front end tool to update this data usually.  Vue, React, or Angular are common javascript frameworks.  Essentially with all of them, the event which is the adding of the item to the cart updates other elements.  You can do all of this with native javascript.

You can also achieve this with page loads.  When you click add to cart, you end up on a new page.  The post request from the add to cart will add the item id to a cart session variable and update the session total cart price to have the same info.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.game_opt').click(function() {
        var available = false;
        var player_game_id = $(this).attr('data-game-id');
        var value = $(this).attr('data-attend-value');

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/attend/'+player_game_id+'/'+value,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function( msg ) {                                                  
                $('#roster_'+msg.game_id).text('('+msg.skaters+')'); 

                if(msg.game_full == 1) {
                    window.location.replace("/waitlist/"+msg.game.id);
                    available = true;
                } else {
                    updateBalance();                    
                }                   
            }
       });
    });
});
```

The update balance is the function I have in another script that sets the balance in the header.

```
function updateBalance() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/players/balance',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function( msg ) {                           
            $('#my_balance').text(msg.balance);
            if (msg.debt == 1) {
                $(".balnce-due-bar").hide().fadeIn();
        } else {
            $(".balnce-due-bar").fadeOut();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! How is it possibile to do it with native javascript?

Comment: I mean is it possible to do it using ajax, but not on page load?

Comment: You can do it with jquery.  You will need to add a class to the add to cart button which will trigger the event.

You will make an ajax call to a php script which will add the item to the cart session variable and return the values you need.  On the successful response you can use jquery to update the price and display the items in a cart hover item if you like.  I will add code example to my answer that is somewhat similar example for a hockey rsvp system I wrote several years ago.